# How do I install libfaudio0?

Tags: software-installation, wine

I'm trying to install the libfaudio0 in Ubuntu 18.04. LTS and [WineHQ tells me](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=32192) I need too add, and I don't know what to do, I don't know how to install these packages How do I install libfaudio from [this repository](https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/)? I have no clue how to do this.

Answer (score 40):

Beginning with Wine 4.5 the wine-devel packages from WineHQ require libfaudio0 as a dependency. The Wine Wiki suggests that both i386 and amd64 libfaudio0 packages should be installed and I illustrate the required steps for Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver, although *similar* steps should work for 18.10 and 19.04:

For Ubuntu 18.04 first download *both* required Debian packages:

```
cd ~/Desktop
wget https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/amd64/libfaudio0_19.07-0~bionic_amd64.deb
wget https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/i386/libfaudio0_19.07-0~bionic_i386.deb
```

if the links are broken, you can still find the files [from here](https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/), you just need to open the i386 and amd64 folders to find the updated files.

Next install the two files and then attend to some missing files:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i libfaudio0_19.07-0~bionic_amd64.deb libfaudio0_19.07-0~bionic_i386.deb
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

And now you should be right to install and run the very latest versions of Wine from WineHQ!

**References:**

- [Wine Wiki: Ubuntu:](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu)  The definitive word on how to install WineHQ packages
- [FAudio for Debian and Ubuntu](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=32192): Links and details on how to install the new requirements of libfaudio0

Comment: Please don't edit to remove distro information from the question. I talked about my opinion on this [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45304497#45304497). Then there was an awful [scope debate](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48848528#48848528) in which some people said that if you know the issue is not distro-specific then go ahead and edit. I disagree with this, but in any case a packaging issue could always be distro-specific, I think.

Comment: to prevent broken links: https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/i386/   https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/amd64/

Comment: it seems like the links provided in this question and on the WINE forums are now private. I get the "Forbidden" error there, 403